# Coverting Hex array to Decimal in Python

Tags: python, binary, hex

I have a Hex Array which looks like :

> 31 31 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

When converting this to binary this looks like : `0011000100110001`

Each bit is a flag that relates to a number within the array. In this case this binary number would equal 2,3,7,10,11,15.

I'm not sure if there is a name for this notation, but is there any easy method to convert the hex about to get a list of decimal numbers as shown above.

So,

Each `0x31` equates to a byte or 8 bits.

Each `0x31` converts to `00110001`.

The way that this binary is then supposed to be interpretted is.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 ......
```

Here you can see I get the decimal values 2,3,7 from the `0x31`.

Hope this makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is a "Hex Array"?  Is it a list of strings?  Is it a string that needs to be parsed?

Comment: How does the hex array look like 0011000100110001 in binary?  I fail to see that conversion, nor how that binary string equals 2,3,7,10,11,15.

Comment: @felix001 In what blaxpirit's or my answer does not answer your question?

Comment: They all looked great answers however Im having quite a few issues running these on 2.4 due to the built in functions that aren't available like bin etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So we have the hex numbers in a space-separated string.

```
s = '31 31 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'
```

Now we split the string, convert each byte from hex string to int (`int('31', 16) == 49`), then convert it to binary string (`bin(49) == '0b110001'`), then take away the `'0b'` with `[2:]`, add zeroes at the beginning so the sequence exactly 8 long (`'110001'.zfill(8) == '00110001'`). Then we join all the bit strings together in one string.

```
s = ''.join(bin(int(b, 16))[2:].zfill(8) for b in s.split())
# Now `s` is '0011000100110001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

- An alternative to the above line, that works in Python 2.5:

  ```
  trans = {'0':'0000','1':'0001','2':'0010','3':'0011','4':'0100','5':'0101','6':'0110','7':'0111','8':'1000','9':'1001','a':'1010','b':'1011','c':'1100','d':'1101','e':'1110','f':'1111',' ':''}
  s = ''.join(trans[c] for c in s.lower())
  ```

Then we [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#enumerate) the bits, so every bit (`b`) will have a corresponding position (`i`), just as you described. We use a list comprehension and include only those positions at which the symbol is `'1'`.

```
r = [i for i, b in enumerate(s) if b=='1']
# Now `r` is [2, 3, 7, 10, 11, 15]
```

Comment: @felix001 Added some explanations.

Comment: +1, expected my version to be significantly faster than converting each byte to a binary string, but I did some timing and this is faster than my bit-shifting approach.

Comment: @F.J The code in the first revision could be even faster, but then I went for (what seemed to me) better clarity.

Comment: Just tried this out but unfortantly Im running Python 2.5.2. Is there a quick way around this as Im unable to upgrade.

Comment: @felix001 OK, I've added a replacement for the line that causes problems in legacy versions of Python...

Comment: Thanks, though Im getting some errors `\n>>> print s
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 A2 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ....
>>> trans = {'0':'0000','1':'0001','2':'0010','3':'0011','4':'0100','5':'0101','6':'0110','7':'0111','8':'1000','9':'1001','a':'1010','b':'1011','c':'1100','d':'1101','e':'1110','f':'1111',' ':''}
>>> s = ''.join(trans[c] for c in s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
KeyError: 'A'`

Comment: @felix001 Ah, it expected the letters to be lowercase. I edited the answer and now it should work fine

Comment: Perfect thanks for all your help. Quick question how would I start the enumeration from another number instead of 0 ?

Comment: @felix001 `enumerate` function can do it, just look in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Transform everything in a big bit string and then enumerate it. Mostly similar to blaxpirit's answer but it does not use the `[:2]` hack.

```
array = [0x31, 0x31, 0, 0, 0]
[i for i, x in enumerate("".join(format(a, "08b") for a in array)) if x == '1']
```

Results in

```
[2, 3, 7, 10, 11, 15]
```

Comment: I'm curious what you thought the [2:] was for. And I don't mean that in a mean, sarcastic way, I am genuinely curious.

Comment: Now it's very nice! I totally forgot about `str.format`. But just [`format`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#format) is even more compact: `format(0x31, '08b') == '00110001'`.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so, first things first, you need to convert that hex array into integer, then to binary. This is pretty simple in python:

```
myBin = bin(int("".join(hexArray),16))[2:].zfill(len(hexArray)*8) #We slice to get rid of the "0b" prepended by the bin function. zfill puts in leading zeros so we don't miss anything
```

Following that, we can do some cool enumeration and list comprehension in order to get the numbers we need:

```
myInts = [off for x, off in enumerate(myBin) if x == "1"]
```

So, assuming you already have your hex in an array, this will give you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: `zip`ping ain't so cool when you've got [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#enumerate), which is perfect for cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

Using a precomputed positions list:

```
arr = [0x31, 0x31, 0, 0, 0]
print [(8*byte_ind + i) for byte_ind, b in enumerate(arr) for i in positions[b]]
# -> [2, 3, 7, 10, 11, 15]
```

Where `positions` maps all (256) bytes to corresponding positions:

```
>>> def num2pos(n):
...     return [i for i, b in enumerate(format(n, '08b')) if b == '1']
... 
>>> positions = map(num2pos, range(0x100))
>>> positions[0x31]
[2, 3, 7]
```

If your array is actually a hex string then you could convert it to a bytearray:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> arr = bytearray(binascii.unhexlify(s.replace(' ', '')))
>>> arr
bytearray(b'11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...\x00')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print int('31', 16)
49
```

From there, you can use a list comprehension or generator expression to do the multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following does what you are looking for:

```
def to_int_list(hex_array):
    hex_str = ''.join(hex_array)
    value = int(hex_str, 16)
    i = 4*len(hex_str) - 1
    result = []
    while value:
        if value & 1:
            result.append(i)
        value = value >> 1
        i -= 1
    return result[::-1]


>>> to_int_list(['31', '31', '00', '00', '00', '00'])
[2, 3, 7, 10, 11, 15]
```

Comment: Thanks, but these didnt seem to work so well...
`>>> to_int_list(z)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in to_int_list
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 A2 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'`

Comment: @felix001 - It wasn't completely clear from your question whether your "array" was a list of strings or one long string.  Try changing the first line to `hex_str = hex_array.replace(' ', '')` and it should work.